# IOS AVAudioSession - How to detect voice without recording it to a file

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I want to detect when user is speaking but don't want to record it to a file (using AVAudioRecorder). Is there any way by which I can directly observe AVAudioSession and achieve this?

```
audioRecorder?.updateMeters()
let power = audioRecorder?.averagePower(forChannel: 0) ?? 0
```

I tried above but it only updates meters when recording is on (which writes to file).

Can't figure out.
Thank you.

Comment: I think meters property is for measuring peak and average sound levels that the recording has so you can display audio levels to the user if you wish to for example.  Can you elaborate on "detect user speaking" ? Does it have to be a person speaking or can it be any type of sound you're trying to detect? Also unless you're specifically saving the file, once AVAudioRecorder writes to file, it'll get cleaned up as it's only a temporary file. Even if it is not, you can probably delete this file yourself as well.

Comment: Yes, it has be a person speaking. Thing is this is going to be long sessions so not keen about writing it to a file. Just to elaborate, app is video calling app, So I want to detect when user speaks while they are on mute (for this i have to constantly listen to mic)

Comment: Maybe you can record but with lower quality which should significantly reduce the size of the recording. Or you can use face detection to trace mouth movements to check if they’re talking. Your question is a bit too open in terms of a solution. Please give more details on why you chose to go a certain way for us to help.